# JSON data fetch header error: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

When I do a GET using Ajax, I get an error on the console screen like this:

> Failed to load https://www.doviz.com/api/v1/golds/all/latest: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.doviz.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://www.elli2.com' is therefore not allowed access.

But when I check the address from the Network tab I see that the data is coming from the data.

The code fragment looks like this:

```js
 $.ajax({
        dataType : "json",
        url : "https://www.doviz.com/api/v1/golds/all/latest",
 headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":'POST,GET,PUT,DELETE',
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":'Authorization, Lang'
    },
        success : function(data){
            var ALTIN = data[5];
            var CHANGE_RATE =  Number(ALTIN["change_rate"]).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("Altin").innerHTML = Number(ALTIN["buying"]).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("AltinOran").innerHTML = CHANGE_RATE > 0 ? "+ %"+CHANGE_RATE : "- %" + CHANGE_RATE;
            document.getElementById("ALTINICON").classList = CHANGE_RATE > 0 ? "fa fa-caret-up" : "fa fa-caret-down";
            document.getElementById("ALTINICON").style.color = CHANGE_RATE > 0 ? "green" : "red";
            document.getElementById("ALTINICON").style.fontSize = "20px";

        }
    })
```

Comment: the problem is not on your side. Is the domain that provide the API that doesn't allow other domains to use it

Comment: The problem is due to the fact that, although the URL you're calling is returning CORS to allow cross-domain requests, it has not allowed the domain you are calling from. There is nothing you can do about this. You will need to contact the oprators of that domain and ask that they whitelist your domain in their CORS restrictions,

Comment: @freedomn-m to be fair to the OP those dupes are about no CORS headers at all. This error is due to the CORS headers not being enabled for the calling domain. I did search for a dupe but couldn't find one. The closest was about ASP.Net Core WebAPI and not strictly relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for clarifying the exact issue.

Comment: OK thanks. I would like to reach out to the site administrators in the direction of yours and add my site to the white list.